# Input Event Handling Issue with JList within Jlist

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom cell renderer for a JList which displays a nested JList inside it with another custom cell renderer that displays a button. The problem I'm having is that any user inputs(e.g. mouse clicks on the buttons, scrolling action) doesn't get handled and the nested JList becomes unreponsive(but it still paints properly whenever I resize the window). Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Renderers are not real components they just paint an image of a component, so yes you are correct, then do not receive any user events.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the info. Then is it possible to relay any keyboard/mouse events to the nested JList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like camickr said, Renderers just paint the image and are not real components.

One way to get around this is to use a single-column JTable, instead of a JList, where you can set CellEditors, which *are* real components (but only once that cell gains focus).

But it actually may be easier to create a panel with a scroll pane that listens to ListData events from a ListModel and adds and removes your components as necessary.  That's what I ended up going with the last time I had this problem, it was a bit more elegant.

Although, if you just have a single button, the JTable may work quite well.